# How to edit Database file?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to change the database at:

```
/data/data/com.android.provider.settings/databases/settings.db
```

I can create new databases with:

```
final String MY_DB_NAME = "Test";
final String MY_DB_TABLE = "Autos";

SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;

myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name varchar(100))");

myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + MY_DB_TABLE + " (name)" + " VALUES ('Audi TT');"); 
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + MY_DB_TABLE + " (name)" + " VALUES ('Honda Civic');");
```

Now, that creates only the name, how can I add the value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getWritableDatabase() to get hold of SQLiteDatabase object. using this object you can do db operations using execSQL.

I usually have all db operations in a seperate class which extends from SQLiteOpenHelper